# Meaning of “vouloir” in “Merci de bien vouloir…”

Tags: sens, politesse

What would “vouloir” mean in this phrase “Merci de bien vouloir…”?

For me it is just a more formal version which no added meaning to the sentence. In which situation should we use this?

Are there similar constructs in which the added words kind of have no meaning but will add formality?

Comment: http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/merci+de+bien+vouloir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is more formal.
In my opinion, it is so much formal, that it becomes ironical, and so is more like a demand than a request. Saying

> Merci de fermer la porte

is already polite, you don't have to add «bien vouloir»...

You could also say

> Merci de bien vouloir vous donner la peine de...

which is even stronger.
It actually means "it is not very difficult to do, so please do it".

Comment: If anything in the given example, it makes the demand softer. It adds a modal to what would otherwise seem like a direct order?

Comment: @GAMPUB Sorry but I don't understand, can you explain ? :)

Comment: Compare *Merci de fermer la porte* with *Merci de bien vouloir fermer la porte*, I find the second one, with the modal, softer.

Comment: @Random, It is not a demand (exigeance) but a request (demande) and you are confusing "stronger" with "softer".

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed, I didn't know that *demand* was a "faux ami", thanks :). About *stronger*, it is not a confusion, I personnaly feel it stronger. It looks like it depends the situation and the person... I'll complete my answer. Thanks

Comment: In context, « Merci de fermer la porte » can be very impolite. It is what people say with an angry tone when they are upset. Expect people to hear the unspoken swearing. « Pourriez-vous » is the simple polite form.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez In an angry context, both « Merci de fermer la porte », « Merci de bien vouloir fermer la porte » are impolite (where the stress is on "la porte")... any sentence is impolite when said with an angry voice... I think it is a different problem...

Comment: @Random: un autre avis sur lequel je viens de tomber: http://dardel.info/Sprache.html#merci

Comment: Je vous prierais de bien vouloir avoir l'obligeance de fermer la porte.

Answer (score 9):

It's the idiomatic formal and polite way to express a request, usually in writing. It is nonetheless a request.

You may want to be careful about the word order. The old-fashioned and very formal usage has two formulas :

- "Merci de vouloir bien..." is meant as an order and implies superiority : it is used when you address your report (or your butler or domestic servant)
- Merci de bien vouloir" is meant as a request

It is unlikely that anybody will notice nowadays (except for someone in the military), and the widely accepted usage is "Merci de bien vouloir".

Answer (score 2):

> Are there similar constructs in which the added words kind of have no meaning but will add formality?

as in "serait-ce un effet de votre haute bienveillance que de bien vouloir considérer xxx" ? :-)
When I was young, we were advised at school (and books) to write any application letter or formal written request that way. But I guess even at that time, this XIXth-century sounding formulation was making human resource people smiling :-)

Comment: I would imagine people rolling their eyes thinking "From which planet this guy is ?" if I say this lol. But perhaps Canadians still use those ? I heard people there are really serious about keeping their French "pure" and classic.

Comment: I would answer or look-like "be straight and simple". But I'm not very patient not polite ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this similar to "Veuillez de fermer la porte" - it's a polite way of saying "Please close the door" - however its literal expression is "Please want to close the door" - which is kind of funny for us in English.

"Merci de bien vouloir" has the same sense of "Please kindly want to..."

Comment: _Veuillez de fermer la porte_ does not exist that I know of. _Veillez à (make sure you) fermer la porte_ is possible, but that's not the same verb (vouloir vs. veiller). Thanks.

Comment: It would be *veuillez fermer*.